# Merge two queries and return one of the possible values

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select value1 as value from T1 where id=10;
```

if `id` does not exist in `T1` - execute another query:

```
select value2 as value from T2 where id=10;
```

So, I want to join these queries and return a single value (`value1` or `value2`). Is it possible?

**SOLUTION:**

My solution:

```
select ifnull(value1, value2) as value from T1 left join T2 using(id) where id=10;
```

Comment: Is there always an entry in T2, or will there only be an entry in T2 if there is no entry in T1? Is there a preference towards the record from T1?

Comment: `T1` can not contain the required id, in contrast to the `T2`

Comment: the preference is implied in the question - "if id does not exist in T1..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY (tested)

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.value1, t2.value2) AS Value FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 USING(id)
WHERE id=10
```

this will always check first the **table t1** for **id=10**, if there is no value then see **table t2**  for the same id

Quoted [FROM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

> The single result column that replaces two common columns is defined
>   using the coalesce operation. That is, for two t1.a and t2.a the
>   resulting single join column a is defined as a = COALESCE(t1.a, t2.a)

Answer (score 3):

you can join the query using union

```
select value1 as value from T1 where id=10 
union 
select value2 as value from T2 where id=10;
```

as a result you can get any one of the value or both

Comment: Thx, but how to filter the result and get only a single value?

Comment: you can do it easily in application level based on the resultset you get from the query

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two queries on the `id` field and then use the `COALESCE` function to combine the two resulting fields into the output.

This assumes that you already have a list of IDs to join against, though. Otherwise you're stuck doing a union or full join to get such a list first.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use this too

```
select Distinct(s1.id) from sample1 as s1 inner join sample2 as s2;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `union` of both

like below :

```
select t1.id from table1 as t1  where id=10
union 
select t2.id from table2 as t2  where id=10
```